# Fix broken python opencv installation

Tags: python, macos, opencv

Seems I have broken opencv python installation:
`pip3 freeze | grep opencv` shows nothing, on `import cv2` I get error:

```
python3
Python 3.7.6 (default, Dec 30 2019, 19:38:26)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.


>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/tbb/lib/libtbbmalloc.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/ceres-solver/lib/libceres.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found


otool -L /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so:
    @rpath/libopencv_reg.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_surface_matching.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_xphoto.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_freetype.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_fuzzy.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_hfs.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_img_hash.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_xobjdetect.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_superres.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_bioinspired.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_dpm.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_face.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_line_descriptor.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_saliency.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_ccalib.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_cvv.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_rgbd.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_structured_light.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_videostab.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_aruco.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_bgsegm.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_optflow.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_sfm.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_stitching.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_objdetect.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_tracking.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_plot.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_dnn.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_datasets.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_photo.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_ximgproc.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_xfeatures2d.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_ml.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_shape.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_video.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_calib3d.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_features2d.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_flann.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_highgui.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_videoio.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_imgproc.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    @rpath/libopencv_core.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 800.7.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.0.0)
```

Is it safe just to remove `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -f /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so

# reinstall opencv from source with python support

# Installing tbb via brew fixed the problem:

brew install tbb
```